# How to order an object by a parameter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, object

I have the following object composed of the following:

[enter image description here][1]

What you see on the screen (the object), is the following: `dataUserProfile.permissions[dataOriginSelect].permissions`

It turns out that I want to order the object according to the `'order'` parameter, from smallest to largest.

I am using something like:

```
const sortByFieldInt = (listToSort,field) => {
  return listToSort.sort((a, b) => {
    if(a[field] < b[field]) {
      return -1;
    }
    if(b[field] < a[field]) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
}
```

which I use like this: `sortByFieldInt([dataUserProfile.permissions[dataOriginSelect].permissions], 'order')`

but it fails me, what am I doing wrong? I really appreciate your time to read me and help.

Comment: That's an array with ONE element. Did you try removing the extra braces?

Comment: How did you call the function?

Comment: 1. Adding code as an image isn't helpful at all. 2. I don't see any array in the picture.

Comment: @caTS I don't understand your recommendation

Comment: @HuyPham `sortByFieldInt([dataUserProfile.permissions[dataOriginSelect].permissions], 'order')`

Comment: Remove the braces: `sortByFieldInt(dataUserProfile.permissions[dataOriginSelect].permissions, 'order')`;

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Indeed it is not, it is not an array of objects.  I tried adding `[ ]` to the object but that doesn't work either.

Comment: @caTS Yes, I also tried it like this and it gives me an error: `TypeError: listToSort.sort is not a function`

Comment: What is `permissions`?

Comment: `dataUserProfile.permissions[dataOriginSelect].permissions` ? is what I attach in the image. Its an object

Comment: `dataUserProfile.permissions[dataOriginSelect].permissions` is an **Object** key - value, not an **Array**. The reason why you could use `listToSort.sort()` function without errors is you passed your object in an `[ ]`. Turn out your array have only one item and that item does not have the `order` key. You must transform your object into array first.

Comment: @HuyPham To transform the object into an array, should I use 'Object.entries()' ?

Comment: It depends on the structure of the object. Try it, you could update the question if any error though.

Comment: @HuyPham Could you look at the image I attached at the end when performing Object.entries() ? I don't understand

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Use `console.log(Object.entries(dataUserProfile.permissions[dataOriginSelect].permissions), null, 2)` so that you get a better representation of the data, and it's accurate as of the time the log was made.

Comment: May you provide the object's content?

Comment: @HuyPham is what I attached in the image of the post

Comment: @HuyPham I don't understand why it creates arrays. It should be an array of objects not an array of arrays with object inside

Comment: Because that's how [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) works.

Comment: @HuyPham so? how can i convert it? because if you leave it that way I can't pass it through my ordering function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform your object into array.

```
const object = dataUserProfile.permissions[dataOriginSelect].permissions; // Your object in this case
console.log(Object.keys(object).map((key) => object[key]));
```

Comment: Yes, it worked for me, I added my sort function to it and it works fine:

`console.log(sortByFieldInt(Object.keys(dataUserProfile.permissions[dataOriginSelect].permissions).map((key) => dataUserProfile.permissions[dataOriginSelect].permissions[key]), 'order'));`

Comment: How can I iterate the array of objects that I stay ordered? Attached image at the end of the post

Comment: I tried with .map() after sorting but I think 'Object.keys' doesn't accept

Comment: There are many ways to iterate an array. Check this thread [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript).